# Trigger After Update in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have a table named **Product** as below:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 51 |
| 3 | 12 |

I want to create a **Trigger** in **Mysql** to take these actions:
If we a have a **new product** added to the table or If a product is **updated**, then **all the product prices** in the table should be **increased by 10** points!

**Example**:
We update the first product updated by (id=1,price=900), then the final table will be as below:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 |
| 2 | 61 |
| 3 | 22 |

I have tried myself to solve this problem by the following command but there was a an error accrued:

```
CREATE trigger increase_price
after update on product.price
begin 
    if NEW.price<> old.price then
        insert into product (id,price)
        values (old.id,old.price+10)
    end if;
end;
```

**ERROR**: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

I would be really thankful if you could help me with this problem :)

Comment: This action cannot be performed in a trigger. Trigger may effect the row which is processed or another table, not another row in the same table. Use according stored procedure instead of single insert/update query.

Comment: I should be implementing the solution with trigger :((( 
But any way i will be greatfull if you could provide the complete code block that you have suggested above, to be more clear

Comment: *I should be implementing the solution with trigger* This is impossible. But you may try nevertheless, of course...

Comment: 'I should be implementing the solution with trigger' - why do you say that?, it's just not possible given the information provided The reason being that an infinite loop could be generated whereby an insert fires a trigger which updates which fires a trigger which inserts etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE add_into_product (p_id INT, p_price INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    
    SET autocommit = OFF;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE product SET price = price + 10;
    INSERT INTO product VALUES (p_id, p_price) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = p_price;
    COMMIT;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7291fa7ad68c7947445a7591429acb6d